# Join query not working the way I want

Tags: php, join, mysqli

I have two MySQLi queries that I am trying to convert to one join query. It's working in a way, but it's not working how I want it to.

I have 2 tables, tickets and replies. I'm selecting the information from the ticket query, and I'm selecting the information from the replies table which has the ticket id stored in there. So far, I'm outputting the initial ticket message and the first reply, but it repeats this for each reply this ticket has. So my current output is this:

```
Initial message
First reply
Initial message
Second reply
Initial message
Third reply
```

It outputs the initial message for each reply that this ticket has. I only want it to output the initial message once and then the replies that this ticket has. So far, I've tried a few different ways of doing this join query, but this is what I have right now:

```
 $ticket = $db->conn->query("SELECT tickets.client, tickets.subject, tickets.message, tickets.created_at, tickets.status,
                                                   replies.reply_username, replies.reply_message, replies.reply_time
                                            FROM tickets, replies
                                            WHERE tickets.id = replies.ticket_id") or die(mysqli_error($db->conn));
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is my logic wrong in a place?

I'd also just like the add that my previous queries have had 'INNER join' and 'left join', but inner gives me the same output the I currently have.

A bit messy, but this is the code that is run after the query.

```
while($rows = $ticket->fetch_object()) {
    if($_SESSION['ticket_username'] == $rows->client) {
        $status = $rows->status;
        echo '
            <h3>'.$rows->subject.'</h3>
            <small>Created by '.$rows->client.', '.$timeAgo->inWords($rows->created_at).'</small>
            <hr>
            <p>'.nl2br($rows->message).'</p>
            <hr>
            <small>Reply from '.$rows->reply_username.', '.$timeAgo->inWords($rows->reply_time).'</small>
            <p>'.nl2br($rows->reply_message).'</p>
            <hr>
        ';

    } else {
        header("Location: index");
    }

    if(!empty($errors) && is_array($errors)) {
        foreach($errors as $error) {
            echo $error;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: paste the whole code after query

Comment: As @PlatinumIndustries said, we'll need the code after; the query you have is going to give you all of the right information. Your issue seems to be in how you're processing it.

Comment: Sorry, I've added the code that is run after the query

Answer (score 1):

You havent given much to go on, but your query seems ok (based on logic), leaving only one possible culprit.

By default **PDO** uses the `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` as its fetch result. Meaning that it maps every column to its name and to an 'integer' column name.

You might need  to use `$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` in your query for the output you expect.

Read more about [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) here.

Answer (score 0):

This may need some tweaking, but here's the way I would approach it:

```
while($rows = $ticket->fetch_object()) {
    if($_SESSION['ticket_username'] == $rows->client) {
        $status = $rows->status;
        if($lastID != $rows->id){
            echo '
                <h3>'.$rows->subject.'</h3>
                <small>Created by '.$rows->client.', '.$timeAgo->inWords($rows->created_at).'</small>
                <hr>
                <p>'.nl2br($rows->message).'</p>
                <hr>';
        }
        $lastID = $rows->id;

        echo '
            <small>Reply from '.$rows->reply_username.', '.$timeAgo->inWords($rows->reply_time).'</small>
            <p>'.nl2br($rows->reply_message).'</p>
            <hr>';

    } else {
        header("Location: index");
    }

    if(!empty($errors) && is_array($errors)) {
        foreach($errors as $error) {
            echo $error;
        }
    }
}
```

What this is doing is checking to see if the currently printed ticket ID is the same as the last one it printed; if it is, don't print the initial message again. I'm not sure how your query is sorting your results, so you may need an `ORDER BY ticket.id, replies.ticket_id` in there to make sure they're all grouped together.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did use and tweak your answer a bit, but got the same result. I've now worked out a workaround method of achieving my result. Similar to yours, I just create a count variable and add one to it as I start to loop through the database result, then use a simple check to see if the count is equal to one and output the initial message.

Comment: Oops. Likely because of how the `lastID` variable is first declared within the `while()` loop. I'm not overly familiar with PHP, but generally defining a variable within a loop will cause it to be declared each time, thus resetting its contents and not allowing that `if` check to function how it should!